# Eclipse: work with external XML-file in a userfriendly way

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java-project in Eclipse. The code is reading a XML-file that is located outside the projects directory.

I want to edit the file in Eclipse.

If I open it (File - open), then it automatically uses the Eclipse XML Editor - what I do not like. I see no possibility to decide to use the Eclipse Generic Editor - that it is possible with project integrated files (rightclick - open with).

And I am not able to import the file into my project because it is outside me projects path.

I can not change the files location.

So what can I do instead of using another editor beside Eclipse to work with the file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the association between *.xml and the editor.

Preferences -> General -> Editor

Now the XML-Editor is not any longer in use.